# to find the distinct element in a list of identical values in python

Tags: python, list

I have a python list containing n elements, out of which n-1 are identical and 1 is not. I need to find the position of the distinct element.

For ex : Consider a python list `[1,1,1,2,1,1]`.
I need the to find out the position of 2 in the list.

I can use a for loop to compare consecutive elements and then use two more for loops to compare those elements with the other elements. But is there a more efficient way to go about it or perhaps a built-in function which I am unaware of?

Comment: One way is to add the elements of the array to a set (which rejects duplicates).  That set will contain exactly two elements.  Pick one of them and count how many times it appears in the array.  If that == 1, you found it.  Otherwise its the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Make a `set` out of it, then count those `set` elements' occurrences in the `list` and find the unique element's `index()` in it.

```
l = [1,1,1,2,1,1]
a,b = set(l)
if l.count(a) == 1:
    unique = l.index(a)
else:
    unique = l.index(b)
```

Result:

```
>>> unique
3
```

Comment: Can be shortened to: `a, b = set(l); unique = l.index(a if l.count(a) == 1 else b)`

Comment: Or `...(a if l.count(a) - 1 else b)`, but I wasn't golfing. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Counter, for example:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1]
c = Counter(a)
for item, count in c.iteritems():
    if count == 1:
        print a.index(item)
```

This would print out 4, the index of 2 in the list a

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly more efficient way (only goes through the list once instead of three times as in [TigerhawkT3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33862531/15055)), but not quite as clean:

```
def find_distinct_index(a):
    if len(a) < 3: raise ValueError("Too short of a list")
    if a[0] == a[1]:
        # it's neither the first nor the second element, so return
        # the index of the leftmost element that is *not* equal to 
        # the first element
        for i, el in enumerate(a):
            if el != a[0]: return i
        raise ValueError("List had no distinct elements")
    else:
        # it's either the first or the second. use the third to figure
        # out which to return
        return a[1] if a[0] == a[2] else a[0]
```